# Find first number in string of numbers

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I have the following string read from a file:

`231 352 502 24 532 0 1234 5`

How do I use a perl regex to grab the first number in a string of numbers?

I have tried the following to no avail:

`$num =~ /(\d+)/`

Thanks.

Comment: $num =~ /(^\d+)/, i hope this will work the value will store in $1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for given sample input, below wokrs fine :

```
$ echo 231 352 502 24 532 0 1234 5 | perl -n -e 'print $1 if /(\d+)(.*)/'
231

$ echo 231 352 502 24 532 0 1234 5 | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)(.*)/\1/'
231
```

Comment: Seems as if (\d+) is correct, however for some reason I am getting all the numbers in the string. I am wondering if my input from the file is weird? I will have to look into this further.

Comment: $line = /(\d+)/;
$line = 231 352 502 24 532 0 1234 5.
It prints the whole line.

Comment: After the match, you should only `$1` which is the 1st match. You are printing the whole line. If you are using sed, then print only `\1`. Check my code above.

Comment: Ah i see! Yes using the $1 gives me what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = "231 352 502 24 532 0 1234 5";
($num) = $s =~ /(\d+)/;
print $num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

Try this

```
my $line = '231 352 502 24 532 0 1234 5';
my ($num) = $line =~ /(\d+)/;
print $num;
```

**output**

```
231
```

Comment: Duplicate answer. This exact code has been provided already in @ooga's answers.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: It is important to *declare* variables as late as possible. What does your tag mean?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/tM7cJ3